# Emacs fuzzy autocompletion

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, fuzzy, ido

I really like `ido`'s fuzzy matching in emacs. I would like to have that with autocompletion. Preferably with `auto-complete`, since I have `ac-python` and other things setup with `auto-complete`. I am aware that `auto-complete` provides fuzzy matching if there are no normal matches found, but I want this normally.

Answer (score 6):

You could just bind `ac-fuzzy-complete` to some key combination you like and use that instead of the other method you are using for completion. It is already interactive, but isn't bound to any key. Something like this would do:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-C-I") 'ac-fuzzy-complete)
```

(<kbd>M-C-i</kbd> is otherwise the key combination used for `complete-symbol`)

Comment: I could, but that would make the popup of `auto-complete` useless and requires extra keys. That defeats the purpose of `auto-complete` for me. Also it and it seems to only give one suggestion.

Comment: It started giving me multiple suggestions, but only a small number like 2, not the normal 9+.

Comment: That controls if fuzzy matching is used if there are no other results. http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#ac-use-fuzzy